# Find distance between two selected coordinates on image using canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to find a length of line and radius of circle on image depend on image width

see below image

[image]

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('loadCanvas'),lastPos, isDown = false;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");          
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);          
    ctx.lineCap = "round";                                   
    ctx.lineWidth = $('#canvasSelWidth').val();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";  
    ctx.strokeStyle = $('#canvasSelColor').val();
    canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
        isDown = true;
        SPos = getPos(e);
        lastPos = getPos(e);
    };
    window.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (!isDown) return;
        var pos = getPos(e);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastPos.x, lastPos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.stroke();
        lastPos = pos;
    };
    window.onmouseup = function(e) {
        isDown = false
        lPos = getPos(e);
        measurementOnImageCanvas();
    };
    function getPos(e) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        xPosition = e.clientX - rect.left;
        yPosition = e.clientY - rect.top;
        return {x: e.clientX - rect.left, y: e.clientY - rect.top}
    }
```

I am use for first coordinate lPos and last SPos.

```
var xCorData = lPos.x - SPos.x
    var yCorData = lPos.y - SPos.y
    var finalPixel =  Math.sqrt( xCorData*xCorData + yCorData*yCorData );
    var centimeters = finalPixel * 2.54 / 96;
    var mm = centimeters*10;
    var inch = mm*0.0393701;
```

Please help me for short out from this problem

Comment: How are you gonna select the coordinates?

Comment: I am select coordinates using mouse click

Answer (score 1):

**Can not be done**

I am assuming you wish to get the physical size of a pixel on the client machine. Unfortunately there is no way to get the display dimensions.

`window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` will get you the resolution of the display but there is no way of knowing the size of the display. Even if it was possible to get the device brand and model you still do not know if it is using its own display or is plugged into another. Even worse, multi display setups may have two or more different screen sizes so that your canvas has regions where the pixel physical size is different.

All you can do is ask the clien to enter the screen dimetions.

**Assuming you have the screen diagonal.**

At the moment I am on a 17.3 laptop with a 1680 by 945 pixel display. To get the pixel size.

Assume that the pixels are square.

```
const mmPerInch = 25.4;  // constant
var screenDiagonal = 17.3 * mmPerInch; // ??? how to get this (17.3) is the problem
var resX = window.screen.width;        // nor do you know if the pixel is square
var resY = window.screen.height;
// now get the number of pixels diagonally
if(typeof Math.hypot === "function"){  // use the new hypot function if available
    var pixelsDiagonal = Math.hypot(resX,resY);
}else{
    var pixelsDiagonal = Math.sqrt(resX*resX+resY*resY);
}
// then divide the screen size by the pixels to get the pixel size.
var pixelSize_mm = screenDiagonal / pixelsDiagonal;
// result pixel is 0.23 by 0.23 mm
```

You now have the size of a pixel in mm and can use that to get a accurate measure of objects you render. But it is no guarantee as the browser may be zoomed in or out.

To convert from pixels to mm just multiply pixel dimensions by pixel size

```
function pixel2mm(pixels){
    return pixels * pixelSize_mm;
}
```

Also asking for the diagonal is no guarantee that the correct value is entered or even known. Also not all pixels are square and that will be even harder to find out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure things on a image more than on the screen, you have all the necessary code, just you needed to tie up togheter.

You have to ASSUME that you are on a 96 DPI device or putting the DPI as a parameter. Also giving a fixed scale for your canvas is the another way to go ( as if you would be on a map ).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('loadCanvas'),lastPos, isDown = false;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");               
    ctx.lineCap = "round";                                   
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;  
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
        isDown = true;
        SPos = getPos(e);
        lastPos = SPos;
    };
    window.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (!isDown) return;
        var pos = getPos(e);
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastPos.x, lastPos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.stroke();
        lPos = pos;
    };
    window.onmouseup = function(e) {
        isDown = false
        lPos = getPos(e);
        measurementOnImageCanvas();
    };
    function getPos(e) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        xPosition = e.clientX - rect.left;
        yPosition = e.clientY - rect.top;
        return {x: e.clientX - rect.left, y: e.clientY - rect.top}
    }
    function  measurementOnImageCanvas() {
    var xCorData = lPos.x - SPos.x
    var yCorData = lPos.y - SPos.y
    var finalPixel =  Math.sqrt( xCorData*xCorData + yCorData*yCorData );
    var inches = finalPixel  / 96;
    var centimeters = inches * 2.54;
    var millimiters = centimeters * 10;
    alert('line lenght:\n' + inches.toFixed(2) + ' inches\n' + centimeters.toFixed(4) + ' centimeters\n' + millimiters.toFixed(2) + ' millimeters\nAssuming you are on a 96 DPI device');
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="loadCanvas" width=500 height=500 />
```